# puppeteer screenshot and send it with a discord command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that takes a screenshot of a specific website(here I'm just using google for example) and send it through discord by command. for some reason it's not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm also fairly new to node.js and discord.js.
I have created a seperate file for all commands and here is the one with puppeteer:

```
const pupp = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = {
    name: 'pup',
    description:'send image',
    execute(client, message, args, Discord){
        (async () => {
            const browser = await pupp.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
            let screenshot = await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
            await browser.close();

        message.channel.send("screenshot",{files: [screenshot]});
      })();
}
}
```

and here is my main.js code:

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
const token = 'TOKEN';

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['commands_handler','events_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})
client.login(token);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the bot isn't crashing when I use the command but it just send the text "screenshot" without the screenshot itself

Comment: have you `console.log()` the screenshot ? Has Puppeteer actually taken a picture ?

Comment: yes it did take the sceenshot

Comment: What is actually stored in `sceenshot` ? I believe that the function is not returning anthing helpful.

Comment: { files: [  <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 03 20 00 00 02 58 08 06 00 00 00 9a 76 82 70 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 20 00 ... 76352 more bytes>} this is what the console.log() shows

Comment: When passing this to the send function of discord.js, you may try to send only the buffer -> `message.channel.send("screenshot",{files: [sceenshot.files[0]});`. Try to look up what `send` is actually expecting as a file input. Maybe it need a base64 encoding.

Comment: when using `message.channel.send("screenshot",{files: [sceenshot.files[0]});` I get an error , Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: because "sceenshot" is `undefined`, it's missing an "r" ;)

Comment: missing the r wasn't the problem , because it was missing from the beginning. I just edited the code. and I tried removing the text from `message.channel.send("screenshot",{files: [screenshot]});` to `message.channel.send({files: [screenshot]});` which acutely worked now it's sending the screenshot